# Compiling VS2015 Typescript\Node.js project from command line using Gulp\Grunt

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript

I'm looking for examples on how to get started with compiling\building a typescript\node project from the command line.

I am aware of Gulp\Grunt as build tools, but I'm looking for an example to help me get started, are there any out there for a developer who has traditional used MS Visual Studio?

Answer (score 0):

Like this article?

http://blog.dmbcllc.com/using-gulp-to-bundle-minify-and-cache-bust/

It is specifically about bundling and minifying but it is all using gulp.  You can add in whatever else you need.

Answer (score 0):

If you are coming from the MS VS land and feel uncomfortable with jumping into the bandwagon of gulp/grunt you can start with this pure NPM way of making builds:

[How to use npm as a build tool](http://blog.keithcirkel.co.uk/how-to-use-npm-as-a-build-tool/)

But eventually I think you will find the flexibility and amount of plugins available in gulp/grunt world worth switching. There are plenty of tutorials out there:

[Automating TypeScript with 
Node And Grunt](http://jessefreeman.com/dev-techniques/automating-typescript-with-node-and-grunt/)

[Creating a TypeScript Workflow with Gulp](http://weblogs.asp.net/dwahlin/creating-a-typescript-workflow-with-gulp)

And so on - google is your friend:).